# Magento 2 GraphQL Tutorial Collection

Tags: magento2, graphql

- https://amasty.com/blog/magento-2-api-updates-graphql/

  - General overview about GraphQL
- https://larsroettig.dev/how-to-create-a-graph-ql-endpoint-for-magento-2-3

  - This Tutorial shows how to create an own Magento 2 GraphQL Endpoint.

Post here what should also cover in a Tutrial or if find helpful tutorial.

Answer (score 10):

I have written some graphQl related articles.Please have a look and share your thoughts.Hope these articles will help some one.

All articles are based on my current project which i found solutions.

1. [What is GraphQl in magento 2.3 and how to access it?](https://www.mujahidh.com/what-is-graphql-in-magento2-3-and-how-to-access-it/)
2. [How to create a graphql schema for magento 2 custom module with custom table?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-create-a-graphql-schema-for-magento-2-custom-module-with-custom-table/)
3. [How to create a Graphql schema by passing argument for custom magento 2.3 module with custom table?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-create-a-graphql-schema-by-passing-argument-for-custom-magento-2-module-with-custom-table/)
4. [How to get product attribute value, label using GraphQl in Magento 2.3?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-get-product-attribute-value-label-using-graphql-in-magento-2-3/)
5. [How to write grapgQl mutation to create and integrate the contact us page functionality in magento 2.3.2?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-write-grapgql-mutation-to-create-and-integrate-the-contact-us-page-functionality-in-magento-2-3-2/)
6. [How to filter product collection with default graphql products query?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-filter-product-collection-with-default-graphql-products-query/)
7. [How to write magento custom search using GraphQl?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-write-magento-custom-search-using-graphql-in-magento-2/)
8. [How to get the store configuration values using GraphQl in magento 2?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-get-the-store-configuration-values-using-graphql-in-magento-2/)

Comment: This is really gold

Comment: @SufyanKhot thank you brother

Answer (score 1):

I have created feedback/contact form with custom fields inserted by Graphql api
You can download my code here
https://github.com/kaushikrohit54/feedback

```
mutation {
  createQueryFeedbacks(
    input: {
      name: "Rohit kaushik"
      mobile: "9876543210"
      email: "rohit.kaushik@example.com"
      feedback: "This is my feedback or query to admin"
      disclaimer: "Yes"
    }
  )
  {
    feedback_submit {
      entity_id
      name
      mobile
      email
      feedback
      disclaimer
    }
  }
}
```